# Is there a way to see ping in Fall Guys?

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

I often feel like I'm lagging, but can't seem to find an option for Ping.

Is there any way to show ping?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. On the PC at least.

You need to run the FallGuysStats.exe and enable the in-game overlay that shows over the game itself. It shows a number of stats including ping.